# Cómo puedo solucionar en php el error UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL?

Tags: php

hice un sitio donde subo fotos al servidor y resulta q con algunas fotos del mismo formato (.jpg) no puedo subirlas debido al error UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL. Del lado del cliente no se está generando ninguna accion q interrumpa el proceso de subida, las fotos tienen el tamaño correcto. como puedo evitar o solucionar este error. 
este es mi codigo

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']) 
AND(($_FILES['archivo']["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
    ($_FILES['archivo']["type"] == "image/jpg") ||
    ($_FILES['archivo']["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ||
    ($_FILES['archivo']["type"] == "image/bmp") ||
    ($_FILES['archivo']["type"] == "image/tiff") ||
    ($_FILES['archivo']["type"] == "image/png"))) {

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],"../".$dirSubir.$_FILES['archivo']['name'])) {
   echo "error al copiar el archivo";
}else {
 echo "el archivo se ha subido con &eacute;xito";
}
                                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la subida de archivos esta siendo interrumpida constantemente, puede ser que necesites aumentar el tamaño máximo de subidas o el tiempo maximo de ejecucion. Para eso podrías intentar revisando las configuraciones en tu PHP.ini y aumentando los siguientes valores:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
max_execution_time
```

O tambien podrías cambiarlas con php usando la funcion ini_set.

Comment: de antemano gracias por la respuesta esto lo intente pero el error se mantiene. De hecho luego de que intento subir alguna de estas fotos que provocan el error  me es imposible seguir navegando. es como si se quedara mareado o a la espera de algo

Comment: Estaba leyendo acerca de ese error y puede ser causado por la instalacion de php con apache2filter, causando un bug con la subida de datos, puedes revisar la siguiente respuesta para ver si solucionas tu problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006344/php-upload-file-error-code-3

Comment: deja revisar gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solía tener un problema similar. Cuando intentaba subir algún archivo, como a los 3/4 de subida me aparecía este error, y sin ninguna interrupción de parte del cliente.
Estaba volviendome loco, y lo único que se me ocurrio fue insertar lo siguiente al final de mi código de PHP.

```
header ("Connection: close");
```

El cual fuerza que se cierre la conexión (Igualmente intenta cerrar la conexión normalmente). Y bueno, eso me resolvió a mi.

Espero que te sirva a ti también o alguien más! Saludos.

Comment: de antemano gracias por la respuesta esto tambien lo intenté pero el error se mantuvo. De hecho luego de que intento subir alguna de estas fotos que provocan el error  me es imposible seguir navegando. es como si se quedara mareado o a la espera de algo. Lo raro es q independientemente del tamaño de las fotos y extension (todas menosres de 2M y jpg) algunas si suben al servidor y otras no.